# postgresql function creation error

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to create the function in PostgreSQL using PGAdmin tool but it giving me syntax error. I am mentioning the function below.

```
create or replace FUNCTION "QTYONHOLDORLOCKOR" (
    M_Product_ID numeric, M_Warehouse_ID numeric,
    M_Locator_ID numeric, LocatorType character varying
) RETURNS numeric as language java
NAME org.compare.sqlj.Product.bomQtyOnHold(int,int,int,java.lang.String) return java.math.BigDecimal';
```

it gives me following Error

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "language"
```

SQL state: 42601

Comment: And what is the error you get?

Comment: ERROR: syntax error at or near "language"
SQL state: 42601

Answer (score 1):

it's because you don't create body of your function between "as" and "language"

```
 create or replace FUNCTION "QTYONHOLDORLOCKOR" (
      M_Product_ID numeric, M_Warehouse_ID numeric,
      M_Locator_ID numeric, LocatorType character varying
  ) RETURNS numeric as 
       $BODY$
            // Your java code here
            return 1;
       $BODY$ 
  language java
```